# Azure Sql Db connection string when using MSI

Tags: azure-sql-database, connection-string

I am trying to figure out the proper Azure sql db connection string to use, when using MSIs

**I am now authenticating to sql via Managed Service Indentities (MSIs)**, and do not have "username and password"

**The connection string type is ADO.NET**

Prior to using MSI, my connection string was in the below format:

Server=tcp:sqlserver.azurenet,1433;Initial Catalog=testdb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={your_username};Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication="Active Directory Password";

Am i simply removing the **User ID={your_username};Password={your_password}**??

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When connecting to Azure SQL using MSI,  the connection authentication method is token. Therefore you cannot use a regular connection string you have indicated above.
There is a C# example available in the MSI tutorial ( see below)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-sql 
although I have not tried it on my own.
Thanks,
Mirek

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Comment: Thank you for the response. That documentation isnt to helpful, as my MSI is for an Azure Function App, contacting Azure SQL database. I am trying to figure out how to write the connection string, to allow authentication for my function app MSI. we are using ADO.NET connection string type

Comment: I have successfully hardcoded the proper Sql db connection string in each of my function app "connection String" settings, using the following CLI code:              az webapp config connection-string set --resource-group $core_rg --name $func_app9 --settings MyDbConnection='Server=tcp:sqlsrv1.database.azure.net.database.windows.net,1433;Database=testdb;' --connection-string-type SQLAzure                                         My Question is: how to i write this out for a Keyvault Secret? Where does the "Type SQLAzure" go in this connection string?