# Azure SQL MSI with PHP (PDO)

Tags: php, azure, pdo, azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity

**Problem:**

I am building a RESTful API. The DBA I'm working with has set up an MSI for gaining access to the production database, which is on an Azure SQL instance. I understand that MSI's are token based, and on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-sql, it has an example written in C#. This does not translate to PHP well, mostly because of my unfamiliarity with C#.

In addition, I am using Lumen to develop the API, which uses PDO for handling the connections. As far as I know, PDO does not have the necessary functionality built in to handle the specialized connection string Azure SQL requires for using an MSI. *See [Azure Sql Db connection string when using MSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52375106/azure-sql-db-connection-string-when-using-msi)*

**Previous research:**

I've read just about every article Microsoft has published about managed identities, and scoured the internet for anyone using managed identities in PHP. Needless to say, the pickings are slim, even more so for this particular use case.

I understand that one could use Key Vault and store the connection string as a note, but I'm 99% sure the system admins won't want this to happen. *What's the point in having the MSI if we're still going to have credentials stored somewhere else?*

Worst case, I suppose I could make the proposition that I need to use a traditional user/password auth flow, despite the powers that be wanting all new projects to use MSIs (we're predominantly a Microsoft shop with a small portion of PHP work).

Posting this is my last ditch effort before presenting my proposition to use Key Vault instead for, at very least, storing the production credentials; the idea of storing a connection string is an anti-pattern in my opinion.

Fundamentally, if someone could provide an example PDO connection string (sqlsrv driver) using an MSI, it would probably move me in the right direction. Any other examples one could provide, or even guidance for how I can use the MSI in this context would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A coworker linked me to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/connection-options?view=sql-server-ver15, will update this question depending on what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/azure-active-directory?view=sql-server-ver15, PDO does have the required functionality. Answering this as the scope of the original question has shifted too far from its original focus.

I now have a support question opened at https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/33678 to determine the best method of utilizing an MSI in Laravel as there is no apparent way to do so based on the code/documentation.